# How to add an old podcast episode to Google Reader, so I find it in my Google Listen app?

Tags: podcast, google-reader, google-listen

I subscribe to podcasts via Google Reader, which puts them on the Google Listen app on my phone. But there are some podcast episodes that are very old that I can see in reader which I want on my phone.

How do I tell reader I want a specific old podcast episode to appear in Google Listen on my phone? Searching old podcasts from the phone is a miserable task.

Comment: Do you mean some very old podcast *episodes?*

Comment: I now edited your question to specify that you're talking about old podcast *episodes* instead of old podcast *feeds*. That way the question is more clear. I hope my assumption was correct.

Answer (score 2):

The syncronization between Google Reader (web) and Google Listen (phone app for listening podcasts) is limited to podcast subscriptions and marking episodes as read/listened and unread/unlistened. There is no direct way to add episodes to your Listen "My listen items" queue from Reader.

You can still access old episodes from Listen by scrolling down and clicking repeatedly on the "Load more episodes..." link at the bottom, and you can add them to queue from there. Of course, this isn't as friendly as selecting them from Reader.

**However, here's a workaround that might work:**

1. In Google Reader, add a specific [tag](http://www.google.com/support/reader/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=69977) of your choice to the old episodes you are interested in.
2. In Google Reader, go to "Manage subcriptions -> Folders and Tags" to make your tag public.
3. Access the public page of the tag to get its Atom feed. That link should be a valid podcast feed containing only the episodes you have tagged (even from multiple different podcasts).
4. *(This is the step I cound't get to work)* Somehow subscribe to that created feed from Listen. Since you can't add a tag directly to a folder in Reader, you need to subscribe to the Atom feed of the tag, and from "Manage subscriptions" add that feed to the "Listen Subscriptions" folder. However, I coulnd't get Listen to show any items in that subscription, even though it looks ok when viewed in Reader.

These questions might also help:

- [Podcast app which supports old episodes well?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4462/podcast-app-which-supports-old-episodes-well)
- [Alternative to Google Listen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2112/alternative-to-google-listen)